# Integrating wrt a measure that is a collection of probability measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure defined on $\mathcal{A} \times \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is some measurable set and $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers. We have that $\mu(a, \cdot)$ is a probability measure so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d}\mu(a, x) = 1$, for all $a \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now, let $f$ be a measurable function that I am currently not imposing any constraints on. I would like to have some sort of result where we have
$$ 
\int_{(a,x) \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathbb{R}} f(a) \mathrm{d} \mu(a,x) = \int_{a \in \mathcal{A}} f(a) \mathrm{d} a.
$$
I was wondering what kind of assumptions do we need to conclude something like this equality? And in what conditions can we extend it to $f$ being a finite measure so that the same expression equals to something like $\int_{a \in \mathcal{A}}\mathrm{d} f(a)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if $\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-finite and $f \colon \mathcal{A} \times \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty]$, you can apply Tonelli's theorem to convert the integral over $\mathcal{A} \times \mathbb{R}$ to an iterated integral.

Comment: Impossible if $da$ refers inetgration w.r.t Lebesgue measure. If $f(a)=1$ for $a=a_0$ and $0$ otherwise then RHS is $0$ and LHS is $1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think my question was wrong and I realized thanks to your counter-example. Shall I post a new question or edit this one? I think what I am wondering is the case when $f$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}$.